# Ruby: Do something when extending an instance with a module

Tags: ruby

I'd like to execute some code when an instance is extended with [Object#extend](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend). A bit like `initialize` when instantiating a class but for a module.

Here is the extended [documentation example](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend):

```
module Mod
  def hello
    "Hello from Mod.\n"
  end
end

class GoodKlass
  def hello
    "Hello from GoodKlass.\n"
  end
end

class BadKlass
  # something totally different
end

good = GoodKlass.new
good.hello         #=> "Hello from GoodKlass.\n"
good.extend(Mod)   #=> #<GoodKlass:0x401b3bc8>
good.hello         #=> "Hello from Mod.\n"
```

For example I'd like to display a warning or raise if `Mod` is used to `extend` something else than an instance of `GoodKlass`:

```
bad = BadKlass.new
bad.extend(Mod)   #=> raise "Mod cannot extend BadKlass"
```

Comment: It's unusual to `extend` an instance as opposed to a class. I'm curious why you want to do that. btw, you have a typo: `expand` should be `extend`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Typo fixed, thanks. I'd like to extend the `File` class, for instance to identify what format it is, for instance `is_jpeg?` and have some methods available to extract metadata like `#date_taken`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define [self.extended](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Module.html#method-i-extended) in the module:

```
module Mod
  def self.extended(base)
    raise "Cannot extend #{base}" unless base.is_a?(GoodKlass)
  end

  def hello
    "Hello from Mod.\n"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your comment on the question, replying to my comment, confirmed a suspicion I had. What you have done is not to extend the class, but to extend a particular instance of the class. Let's see what your code does.

```
good = GoodKlass.new
good.hello       #=> "Hello from GoodKlass.\n"
GoodKlass.hello  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for GoodKlass:Class
good.extend(Mod)
GoodKlass.hello  #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for GoodKlass:Class
good.hello       #=> "Hello from Mod.\n"
very_good = GoodKlass.new
very_good.hello  #=> "Hello from GoodKlass.\n"
```

As you see, `hello` is only defined on the instance `good`.

Note

```
GoodKlass.methods.include?(:hello)          #=> false
good.methods.include?(:hello)               #=> true
```

If that's not what you want, there are two possibilities. I reference

```
class VeryGoodKlass
end
```

in discussing both.

*1. `Extend` the class*

In your application (ref comments on the question), this approach would allow you to a create a class method `File::jpg?` which would be invoked `File.jpeg?("cat.jpg")`.

To convert `Mod`'s instance method `hello` to a class method of `GoodKlass` you need to extend the class (not an instance of the class), using [Object#extend](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend). To prevent other classes from extending the module, use the callback method [Module#extended](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-extended) in the module.

```
module Mod
  def self.extended(base)
    raise ArgumentError, "Cannot extend #{base}" unless base == GoodKlass
  end
  def hello
    "Hello from Mod"
  end
end

class GoodKlass
  def self.hello
    "Hello from GoodKlass"
  end
end

GoodKlass.hello           #=> "Hello from GoodKlass"
GoodKlass.extend(Mod)
GoodKlass.hello           #=> "Hello from Mod"
VeryGoodKlass.extend(Mod) #=> ArgumentError: Cannot extend VeryGoodKlass
```

*2. Include the module in the class*

To add `Mod`'s instance methods to `GoodKlass` (keeping them instance methods) you need to include the module, using [Module#include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-include). To prevent other classes from including the module, use the callback method [#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-i-included) in the module.

In your application this would allow you to write an instance method `File#jpg?`<sup>1</sup> used as follows:

```
f = File.new('cat.jpg')
f.jpg?
```

You could do that as follows.

```
module Mod
  def self.included(base)
    raise ArgumentError, "Cannot include #{base}" unless base == GoodKlass
  end
  def hello
    "Hello"
  end
end

class GoodKlass
end

good = GoodKlass.new
GoodKlass.include(Mod)
GoodKlass.hello            #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `hello' for GoodKlass:Class
good.hello                 #=> "Hello" 
VeryGoodKlass.include(Mod) #=> ArgumentError: Cannot include VeryGoodKlass
```

<sup>1. Perhaps `File.basename(f.path).end_with?(".jpg")`.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, you got my idea about extending the instance. As what I'm trying to do is too long for a comment, I posted a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163187/ruby-file-formats-handling-by-extending-file-with-a-module